# Display 2 Random Divs From Array Without Repeating in PHP

Tags: php, html, random

I want to display two Divs from an array at random without the same Div displaying twice.

This is what I've been using to display 1 Div at random

```
<?
$divs = array('<div id="divFirst">First Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Second Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Third Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Fourth Div</div>');
shuffle($divs);
print array_shift($divs);  
?>
```

I need to generate a unique pair of random numbers in PHP, Then I should be able to figure out how to make two divs in an array display.

I've searched for this question a lot. And while there are many questions on random non repeating numbers I can't find one for PHP, that doesn't use jQuery, SQL, Javascript or works on modern versions of PHP

Comment: I dont like that all of your divs have the same id :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**array_rand()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get 2 random keys from the array:

```
$divs = array('<div id="divFirst">First Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Second Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Third Div</div>','<div id="divFirst">Fourth Div</div>');

// Array with 2 random keys from $divs
$randKeys = array_rand($divs, 2);

echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; // First random div
echo $divs[$randKeys[1]]; // Second random div
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/9Yktqr1e)

Comment: Wouldnt this potentially return the same result twice in a row?

Comment: @dcc Only if the same div appears twice in the array. It won't repeat the same *key* twice, but it has no say over the *value* of the element. I didn't see any repeating values in the OP's array - but if there were you could prevent duplicates by first calling `array_unique`, then grabbing the random keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function to fetch the 2 random divs,

> $results = array_rand($divs, 2);
>
> echo $divs[$results[0]];  // First Div
> echo $divs[$results[1]];  // Second Div